setting LAYERSERIES_COMPAT_
In the bitbake "hello, world" example I am attempting to resolve the WARNING:
*
WARNING: Layer hello should set LAYERSERIES_COMPAT_hello in its conf/layer.conf file to list the core layer names it is compatible with.
*
This is my layer.conf file:
BBPATH .= ":${LAYERDIR}"
BBFILES += "${LAYERDIR}/*.bb"
BBFILE_COLLECTIONS += "hello"
BBFILE_PATTERN_hello := "^${LAYERDIR_RE}/"
LAYERSERIES_COMPAT_hello = "sumo"

If I do not added the LAYERIES_COMPAT_hello assignment I get the warning but if I add this line I get this error:
*
ERROR: No core layer found to work with layer 'hello'. Missing entry in bblayers.conf?
*
Can anyone provide an explanation? I believe I am doing exactly what the hint is asking? Also provide a solution if possible.
Being able to run bitbake "hello, world" without any warnings.

Why are you using EOL sumo layer? What happens when you try more recent revisions like "kirkstone"? What is `bitbake "hello, world"? If it's your recipe name, I storngly suggest changing it to fit the other recipes (like packet-name_packetversion.bb)
